# Trying to replace segment of img src | Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an enjin site for a friend. One of the parts is an award showcase but it is stuck on showing the "small" version of the award photo and can't be changed. However the difference between the small and large version is literally just one part of the source URL where it says /small/ you change it to /large/ and it displays the correct version. I tried creating a function using JavaScript to do this for me as there is a constantly changing number of awards on screen that all need their "large" version shown however I keep getting this error and nothing changes:

```
Cannot read property 'replace' at undefined members:467
```

This is all my JavaScript for the page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#memberBlock" ).insertAfter( "#page" );
    $( "#memberContainer" ).append($("div.m_members"));

    // This is the code I tried using to change all the img's src
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        $("img").each(function() {
            $(this).src = $(this).src.replace("small", "large");
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery object doesn't provide the attribute `src`.

**You can do the following:**

```
this.src = this.src.replace("small", "large");
```

The object `this` is a native IMG DOMElement which provides the attribute `src`.

**Another alternative is setting the `src` through the function `attr`:**

```
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("small", "large"));
```